# How do I create a script to sort values from multiple lists and add them to empty lists?

Tags: python

I want to create a script that will classify weather stations based on their average annual temp. I have a few lists created as a test. I am new to python and am unsure of how to sort specific items from these lists into empty lists. My criteria for sorting is: if the temperature >50 I want to sort that zipcode into ZoneAZips and <= 50 into ZoneBZips. I then also want to add the temperatures to the 'temp = []' list. Here is what I have written so far:

```
temp = []
ZoneAZips = []
ZoneBZips = []
# Define the classify function to add the station's zip code
# to the appropriate list and add the annual temperature to the temp list.

classify(["Station278", 54321, 48])
classify(["Station452", 12432, 42])
classify(["Station938", 72123, 53])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare your temperate (index=2) to 50 and then decide into which list you want to append the zipCode. Finally append the temperature always to temp.

```py
def classify(data):
    if data[2] > 50:
        ZoneAZips.append(data[1])
    else:
        ZoneBZips.append(data[1])
    temp.append(data[2])
```